# Python3 sort IP addresses 4, 6 and Hostnames

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am looking at writing a function which sorts IP address (both IPv4 & 6) along with hostnames. e.g.

```
127.0.0.1
test.com
10.10.23.4
98.137.246.8
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
98.137.246.7
```

I have already tried this code, which only works for IPv4. Could somebody help write a function to sort all if they exist?

```
sorted(sorted_ips, key=lambda ip: struct.unpack("!L", inet_aton(ip))[0])
```

The output should be, therefore sorting in ascending order of addresses.

```
10.10.23.4
98.137.246.7
98.137.246.8
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
test.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What ordering should be applied…?

Comment: So, first IPv4s, then IPv6s, both in *logical* order (e.g. `2.x.x.x`, `100.x.x.x`), then host names last, in *ascending* order?

Comment: @deceze yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

One way using `ipaddress.ip_address`:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address

def ipsorter(s):
    try:
        ip = int(ip_address(s))
    except ValueError:
        return (1, s)
    return (0, ip)

sorted(l, key=ipsorter)
```

Output:

```
['10.10.23.4',
 '98.137.246.7',
 '98.137.246.8',
 '127.0.0.1',
 '2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334',
 'test.com']
```

Comment: In case of a `ValueError`, you should probably `return s` in some way, to sort host names alphabetically…

Comment: @deceze hmm.. good idea but can't think of general way of comparing all the ips and text altogether :P

Comment: Returning tuples like `(1, ...)`, `(2, ...)`, `(3, ...)`, where the first value depends on the type of `s`, would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @deceze Wonderful ;) I've made an update. Learn by answering, yay!